# Purposefully disable history for a particular file in Git while keeping most recent version

Tags: git, binary, binaryfiles, revision-history

I am using a proprietary database language for development of my program.  The source code is stored in large binaries, and I use a code export utility to save my source code in plain text before committing to my git repository.  Since my active source code file is a large binary, I want to update that file in the repository, but I do not care to keep a history for it.  The IDE I am using always makes it appear as if the binary has changed, even if I have only made changes to external component files (e.g. xml, manipulated test data, etc...).  My question is this:

**How can I make git keep only the latest version of this particular binary file, so as to save space in my central repository server?  Essentially, I do not want to track history for this particular file, but I still want to keep the most recent copy in my repository.**

I searched Google and Stack Exchange for an answer, and I have found similar questions, but no answers for Git.

Comment: It might be the case that this particular file lives *outside* of Git since you don't want to track it.  Is it possible for you to set up a system that allows you to download it from an intranet server?

Comment: @Makoto Yes I can do that.   I was thinking of using a githook maybe to set it to download when people are populating a new local branch.  That was the solution I thought I might be able to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The source code is stored in large binaries, and I use a code export utility to save my source code in plain text

> How can I make git keep only the latest version of this particular binary file

To keep only one original-binary version in the repository, not tied to any version of your exported-to-text source, the simplest will be to talk directly to Git's content tracker core for that file:

```
git tag latest-binary $(git hash-object -w that.file)
```

which bypasses almost all of Git and everything else, and makes a reference directly to the bits.  You won't be able to check it out normally, instead, use

```
git show latest-binary >any.name.you.like
```

Answer (score -2):

You can remove the file from history and stop tracking it by

```
git rm --cached FILE
```

possibly you want to add the FILE to .gitignore and add that too

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "removed binary FILE from index"
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch FILE" HEAD
```

Now your history should be cleaned.

**Though this should work without loosing the FILE, you should make a backup of the file.**

#### BUT

That means you don't have that file in your repository! It just lives in the directory of your working copy. You cannot push that file or whatever.

*It is impossible to not track a file, that is part of the repository, as far as I know. If it can be achieved somehow, it is a very dirty trick.*

### *Negative Votes*

As I seem to gain negative votes for this answer: The first line is (for major implications sake), only a line to discontinue tracking the file, from now on, not the whole history, but it will leave the file itself in the file system. Using .gitignore makes the file "invisible" for git commands (to possibly remind you, that the file is here for a purpose).

The sentence is not closed, so linguistically, the the whole sentence makes sense, as the final block will then remove the file from history.

Mr. Chris proposes not to use filter-branch, but you cannot modify history, without using filter-branch, which is what filter-branch is for: To modify history.

And yes, this is a serious operation with quite some impact, as we all learned from "Back to the Future", every modification in history is.

But this is the purpose of the question.

In some use cases though, removing file from history is actually needed, for example if you have private keys, passwords or other security relevant data in a public git repository.

And, by the way, I already warned the reader of the answer about the implications, with the following statements (in bold font!) and the big "But", that the file is no longer tracked and to better make a backup copy, before trying this.

### Conclusion

The question makes sense and is very serious in some context and the answer works, so the answer is an important method to fullfill a relevant operation on git repositories.

Thus the comment is wrong from some, if not any directions.

If the one who commented here, would provide a different, less impacting solution on a repository, the comment would possibly make sense, but I don't think that you can find a save way to modify history.

If you don't believe me, watch the movie "Back to the future."

As long as there are no other solutions to do such an operation, where you can find *very serious* use cases for, it is still the best answer one can get.

*I will not flag the comment though, as though wrong with respect to the context, it is still a good comment to make you think twice about what you are doing, when you do `filter-branch`.*

Comment: `git rm --cached` will *not* remove the file from your history. And using `git filter-branch` will change commit hashes from the first commit that contains the file all the way to the most recent commits on any branches based off that commit. This has *major* implications that should always be carefully explained; please don't ever recommend using `git filter-branch` without doing so.

Comment: The comment is invalid as the @Chris, does not provide an alternative. I commented about this comment in the answers text under "Negative Votes".
Yes the operation is dangerous, but thats the whole topic. Modifying history is dangerous in a general and in this special context.

Comment: BTW: Of course you also cannot modify a git history, without modifying the hashes of each modified commit, so from the point in time, the modification took place.